# Is there a "curl" for flash video?

Tags: command-line, flash

I do not want to install a flash plugin into my browser for security reasons.

There is also a website that I use that requires flash.... Not making an exception for this site.

So, I was thinking, is there a CLI tool similar to `curl` but for flash content that will play the content merely by providing a URL? For ex: `some_tool http://example.com/blah.swf` ?

Kind of like `mplayer` or other CLI music players.

Answer (score 1):

since `mplayer` can stream (and save stream) and play swf files, I was using it to play online flash videos for a long time, but you have to go through page source etc so it works but it's fun only for some of us.

however what you are looking for is probably `youtube-dl` (it supports much more then youtube, and can also download subtitles, playlists etc).

also please note we have https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ site (I know! I was surprised too!:) and your question might be a better fit there.